# Why data isn't storing with controller@store method

Tags: php, html, laravel

I used method store from a controller and data doesn't store in my database.

I want to insert `NOM_ARTICLE`, `PHOTO_ARTICLE`, `TYPE`, `DESCRIPTION_ARTICLE` in three tables from a form in native HTML, but I don't know what action to do.

I am using ArticleController where there is a method `store` and three table models.

```php
public function create()
{
    return view('addarticle');
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $article = new article;
    $article->NOM_ARTICLE = $request->NOM_ARTICLE;
    $article->LABEL_TYPE = $request->LABEL_TYPE;
    $article->PHOTO_ARTICLE = $request->PHOTO_ARTICLE;
    $article->DESCRIPTION_ARTICLE = $request->DESCRIPTION_ARTICLE;
    $article->save();

    return redirect()->route('addarticle');
}
```

Here are my tables from database:

```
article ('ID_ARTICLE','NOM_ARTICLE','ID_TYPE,'DESCRIPTION_ARTICLE')
photo_articles('ID_PHOTO','ID_ARTICLE','PHOTO_ARTICLE') 
type('ID_TYPE','TYPE')
```

My HTML form:

```
<form method="post" action="" class="contact_form text-center" id="contact_form">
  <div class="">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <input type="text" class="contact_input" name="NOM_ARTICLE" placeholder="Nom d'article" required="required">
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <input type="text" class="contact_input" name="ID_TYPE" placeholder="Type d'article" required="required">
    </div>
    <div>  
      <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="250000" />
      <input type="file" class="contact_input" name="PHOTO_ARTICLE" placeholder="Capture de votre article" name="fic" size=50 required="required" />
      <!--  <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" /> -->
    </div>

  </div>
  <textarea class="contact_textarea contact_input" name="DESCRIPTION_ARTICLE"placeholder="Description" required="required"></textarea>
  <button class="contact_button" type="submit">Valider!</button>
</form>
```

And I have my route in web.php:

```
Route::resource('addarticle','ArticleController');
```

And this is my Article model:

```
<?php
  namespace App;
  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

  class article extends Model {
    public $table = 'article';
    public $primaryKey ='ID_ARTICLE';
    return $this->belongsTo('photo_articles');
  }
```

After I click on the submit button it shows a URL like this: http://localhost/testprojet/public/addarticle?NOM_ARTICLE=test&ID_TYPE=book&MAX_FILE_SIZE=250000&PHOTO_ARTICLE=villle+icon.jpg&DESCRIPTION_ARTICLE=ss

And redirecting to my view `addarticle` but nothing gets added in the database.

Comment: Please can you add the code from your `article` model?

Comment: this is my article model :
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class article extends Model
{
    
    public $table = 'article';

    public $primaryKey ='ID_ARTICLE';
    return $this->belongsTo('photo_articles');
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yaa You clearly missed csrf token to pass with the form. If you want to bubmit any form in Laravel, you should pass csrf token.

use @csrf and blade will pass the unique token to the form submit

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf

Example:

```
<form method="post" action="" class="contact_form text-center" id="contact_form">
    @csrf
    <div class="">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <input type="text" class="contact_input" name="NOM_ARTICLE" placeholder="Nom d'article" required="required">
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <input type="text" class="contact_input" name="ID_TYPE" placeholder="Type d'article" required="required">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="250000"/>
            <input type="file" class="contact_input" name="PHOTO_ARTICLE" placeholder="Capture de votre article" name="fic" size=50 required="required"/>
            <!--  <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" /> -->
        </div>

    </div>
    <textarea class="contact_textarea contact_input" name="DESCRIPTION_ARTICLE" placeholder="Description"
              required="required"></textarea>
    <button class="contact_button" type="submit">Valider!</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I see from your `form` is that you didn't put any action in it, you just left it empty:

```
<form method="post" action="" class="contact_form text-center" id="contact_form">
```

You should be putting in a route to your `store` method in your controller, so that when the form is submitted, the data will be passed into your controller.

Also, providing a link to your `localhost` isn't helping us to understand your problem as we can't access to it. A solid screenshot will do.

Comment: Screen shot shows that he redirected me to "addarticle" without error showing the url that i posted wich mean he used the function store but nothing stores in the database

Answer (score 0):

You should put the action according to the resource pattern.

Your **web.php**

```
Route::resource('articles','ArticleController');
```

Your form:

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('articles.store')}}" class="contact_form text-center" id="contact_form">
@csrf
```

You should include the [`@csrf`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf) blade directive, as well.

In you controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $article = new Article();
    $article->NOM_ARTICLE = $request->NOM_ARTICLE;
    $article->DESCRIPTION_ARTICLE = $request->DESCRIPTION_ARTICLE;
    $article->save();

    return redirect()->route('addarticle');
}
```

You're adding the `PHOTO_ARTICLE` to the article but you dont have this column in your articles table as you said, so it dont make sense to use the line below:

```
$article->PHOTO_ARTICLE = $request->PHOTO_ARTICLE;
```

Also, you're not receiving any `LABEL_TYPE` from your request, and you dont have this column in your articles table too. So you must remove this line:

```
$article->LABEL_TYPE = $request->LABEL_TYPE;
```

Comment: thanks for answering first, ijust wanna add that i have to add data from the form in three tables based on the three models i created

Answer (score 0):

Try this: I hope it will help you.

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $articleObj = new article;
    $articleObj->add($request);

    //second table
    $employerObj = new Employer();
    $employerObj->add($request);
}
```

Create three model according to your datatables and paste this code for all.

```
function add($request)
{
    $this->NOM_ARTICLE = $request->NOM_ARTICLE;
    $this->LABEL_TYPE = $request->LABEL_TYPE;
    $this->PHOTO_ARTICLE = $request->PHOTO_ARTICLE;
    $this->PHOTO_ARTICLE = $request->PHOTO_ARTICLE;
    $this->save();

    return $this->id;
}
```